# How much can I rely on Java's garbage collection (Groovy)?

Tags: java, groovy, garbage-collection

I have a statusbar in a Swing application that continuously prints status. All objects and classes within the application will be using this setStatus method to paint the status bar

```
public def setStatus(statusText){       
        Thread.start {
             ljaStatusBarButton.setText("Status : $statusText . . . .")
             sleep(3000)
             ljaStatusBarButton.setText("Status : Waiting for user action . . . .")
                     interrupt() // or stop() ?  
        }
    }
```

The status bar will display the status for 3 sec and revert back to a status saying waiting for user action.

This does work correctly but my concern is that the above method will be call multiple times from the UI which also means a new Thread object will be created everytime a status is set. Keeping this is mind, I've explicitly added a `interrupt()` at the end as I want to indicate the compiler that I am not in need of this thread anymore. And also, how much can I bet on Java's garbage collection to ensure that the stopped/interrupted threads will be cleaned up soon? Or is there a better workaround for this multiple thread objects issue?

Comment: On a sidenote, if that's Swing, then you shouldn't be modifying Swing controls on anything but the Swing Event Thread. Have a look at SwingUtilities' invokeAndWait or invokeLater methods for how to invoke code on the Event Thread from a background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect as you are using Swing outside of the EDT

As you are using groovy already, why not use the SwingBuilder helpers that were added to make this sort of thing easier?

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

...

public def setStatus( statusText ) {
  // If we are not already on the EDT, static SwingBuilder.build(Closure) will do that for us.
  // In the case of an event handler like the actionPerformed for the button, then naturally
  // we're on the EDT already and the building will continue immediately.
  SwingBuilder.build {

    // doOutside will run the following code in our own thread
    doOutside {

      // Then change the swing components back on the EDT
      edt {
        ljaStatusBarButton.text = "Status : $statusText . . . ."
      }

      // So this sleep is in our own thread again (from doOutside)
      sleep(3000)

      // Then change the swing components back on the EDT
      edt {
        ljaStatusBarButton.text = "Status : Waiting for user action . . . ."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Taken in part from the [MultiThreading with SwingBuilder example](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Multithreading+with+SwingBuilder)

Comment: This looks a lot convincing. Now no matter how many times the setStatus() is called, only the single instance of EDT takes care of it right? I don't have to bother about multiple thread instances, isn't it?

Comment: @VeeKay Did you look at the link provided?  I have commented the code to show what it is doing...  `doOutside` will create a `Thread` for you, and the code inside the `edt` blocks will be run on the correct thread for updating Swing components

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `interrupt()`.

In Java, a thread ends when the `run()` method completes (either normally by returning, or abnormally by throwing an exception).

This means that as soon as your second `setText()` call is executed, the `Thread` will stop running. And since nothing else references the `Thread` object that was created, it will sooner or later be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Garbage collection will free the space your Thread uses at least when it's needed for another Object. You don't have to care about when it happens, if you need the space, you get it.